# Couldn't start JMS Connection

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I am not able to start the JMS Connection, where the connection is created with ActiveMQConnectionFactory. Below is my code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
    try {
        broker.setUseJmx(true);
        broker.addConnector("vm://localhost:61616");
        broker.start();
        System.out.println("Broker started from EventManager  >>>");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        ProducerConsumer pc = ProducerConsumer.getInstance();
        pc.sendMessage("TESTQ", "Hello");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

ProducerConsumer Java Class :

```
   public static ProducerConsumer getInstance() throws Exception {
    if(produceConsume == null) {
        System.out.println(" synchronized Instanace created ");
        produceConsume = new ProducerConsumer();
    }
    return produceConsume;


private ProducerConsumer() throws Exception 
    {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(this.url);
        try {
            this.connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            this.connection.start();
        } catch (JMSException jms) {
            throw new Exception("Exception when active MQ establishes connections....", jms);
        }
    }
```

The code get stuck at start(), with the thread dump I can see the below stack

> Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.0-b28 mixed
>   mode):
>
> "ActiveMQ Task-1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fbe3c414800 nid=0x3543 in
>   Object.wait() [0x00007fbe2a715000]    java.lang.Thread.State:
>   TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)     at java.lang.Object.wait(Native
>   Method)
>     - waiting on <0x00000007d7443228> (a java.lang.Object)  at org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport.doReconnect(FailoverTransport.java:954)
>     - locked <0x00000007d7443228> (a java.lang.Object)  at org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport$2.iterate(FailoverTransport.java:136)
>     - locked <0x00000007d7443218> (a java.lang.Object)  at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner.runTask(PooledTaskRunner.java:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner$1.run(PooledTaskRunner.java:48)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
>
> "ActiveMQConnection[ID:ayush-0791-50867-1412762440207-2:1] Scheduler"
>   daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fbe3c413000 nid=0x3542 in Object.wait()
>   [0x00007fbe2a816000]    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object
>   monitor)  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
>     - waiting on <0x00000007d75d73a8> (a java.util.TaskQueue)   at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)   at
>   java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:526)
>     - locked <0x00000007d75d73a8> (a java.util.TaskQueue)   at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
>
> "ActiveMQ Broker[localhost] Scheduler" daemon prio=10
>   tid=0x00007fbe3c3e0000 nid=0x3541 in Object.wait()
>   [0x00007fbe2a917000]    java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on
>   object monitor)   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
>     - waiting on <0x00000007d93fa080> (a java.util.TaskQueue)   at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
>     - locked <0x00000007d93fa080> (a java.util.TaskQueue)   at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
>
> "ActiveMQ Data File Writer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fbe3c3d1800
>   nid=0x3540 in Object.wait() [0x00007fbe2aa18000]
>   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)   at
>   java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
>     - waiting on <0x00000007d93fa3b8> (a org.apache.kahadb.journal.DataFileAppender$1)  at
>   java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)    at
>   org.apache.kahadb.journal.DataFileAppender.processQueue(DataFileAppender.java:312)
>     - locked <0x00000007d93fa3b8> (a org.apache.kahadb.journal.DataFileAppender$1)  at
>   org.apache.kahadb.journal.DataFileAppender$2.run(DataFileAppender.java:203)
>
> "ActiveMQ Journal Checkpoint Worker" daemon prio=10
>   tid=0x00007fbe3c3cb000 nid=0x353f waiting on condition
>   [0x00007fbe2ab19000]    java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING
>   (sleeping)    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)    at
>   org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase$3.run(MessageDatabase.java:296)
>
> "KahaDB Scheduler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fbe3c3c1000 nid=0x353e in
>   Object.wait() [0x00007fbe2b32b000]    java.lang.Thread.State:
>   TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)     at java.lang.Object.wait(Native
>   Method)
>     - waiting on <0x00000007d981f418> (a java.util.TaskQueue)   at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
>     - locked <0x00000007d981f418> (a java.util.TaskQueue)   at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
>
> "RMI RenewClean-[192.168.57.33:47976]" daemon prio=10
>   tid=0x00007fbde0005800 nid=0x353c in Object.wait()
>   [0x00007fbe2ad1b000]    java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on
>   object monitor)   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
>     - waiting on <0x00000007d9889870> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)     at
>   java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
>     - locked <0x00000007d9889870> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.DGCClient$EndpointEntry$RenewCleanThread.run(DGCClient.java:535)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
>
> "RMI Scheduler(0)" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fbdf0024800 nid=0x353b
>   waiting on condition [0x00007fbe2ae1c000]    java.lang.Thread.State:
>   TIMED_WAITING (parking)   at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
>     - parking to wait for  <0x00000007850ffb10> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2082)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1090)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:807)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1043)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1103)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
>
> "GC Daemon" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fbdf0006800 nid=0x3539 in
>   Object.wait() [0x00007fbe2b028000]    java.lang.Thread.State:
>   TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)     at java.lang.Object.wait(Native
>   Method)
>     - waiting on <0x00000007850069b0> (a sun.misc.GC$LatencyLock)   at sun.misc.GC$Daemon.run(GC.java:117)
>     - locked <0x00000007850069b0> (a sun.misc.GC$LatencyLock)
>
> "RMI Reaper" prio=10 tid=0x00007fbdf0004800 nid=0x3538 in
>   Object.wait() [0x00007fbe2b129000]    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
>   (on object monitor)   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
>     - waiting on <0x0000000785000b98> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)     at
>   java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
>     - locked <0x0000000785000b98> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)     at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.ObjectTable$Reaper.run(ObjectTable.java:351)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
>
> "RMI TCP Accept-0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fbdf0003000 nid=0x3537
>   runnable [0x00007fbe2b22a000]    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE     at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)  at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:398)
>     at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:522)  at
>   java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:490)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(TCPTransport.java:388)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(TCPTransport.java:360)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
>
> "RMI TCP Accept-1099" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fbe3c318000 nid=0x3535
>   runnable [0x00007fbe2b42c000]    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE     at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)  at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:398)
>     at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:522)  at
>   java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:490)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(TCPTransport.java:388)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(TCPTransport.java:360)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
>
> "Service Thread" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fbe3c097800 nid=0x3533
>   runnable [0x0000000000000000]    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
>
> "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fbe3c095800 nid=0x3532
>   waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]    java.lang.Thread.State:
>   RUNNABLE
>
> "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fbe3c092800 nid=0x3531
>   waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]    java.lang.Thread.State:
>   RUNNABLE
>
> "Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fbe3c090800 nid=0x3530
>   waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]    java.lang.Thread.State:
>   RUNNABLE
>
> "Finalizer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fbe3c071800 nid=0x352e in
>   Object.wait() [0x00007fbe389f8000]    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
>   (on object monitor)   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
>     - waiting on <0x000000078500efa8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)     at
>   java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
>     - locked <0x000000078500efa8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)     at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)     at
>   java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:177)
>
> "Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fbe3c06f800 nid=0x352d
>   in Object.wait() [0x00007fbe38af9000]    java.lang.Thread.State:
>   WAITING (on object monitor)   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
>     - waiting on <0x000000078500ee20> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)   at
>   java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:133)
>     - locked <0x000000078500ee20> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
>
> "main" prio=10 tid=0x00007fbe3c00c000 nid=0x3523 in Object.wait()
>   [0x00007fbe44f01000]    java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on
>   object monitor)   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
>     - waiting on <0x00000007d7443208> (a java.lang.Object)  at org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport.oneway(FailoverTransport.java:516)
>     - locked <0x00000007d7443208> (a java.lang.Object)  at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.oneway(MutexTransport.java:40)
>     - locked <0x00000007d75642c8> (a java.lang.Object)  at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.asyncRequest(ResponseCorrelator.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.request(ResponseCorrelator.java:86)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1284)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.ensureConnectionInfoSent(ActiveMQConnection.java:1392)
>     - locked <0x00000007d75a9aa8> (a java.lang.Object)  at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.start(ActiveMQConnection.java:504)
>     at test.ProducerConsumer.(ProducerConsumer.java:37)   at
>   test.ProducerConsumer.getInstance(ProducerConsumer.java:16)   at
>   test.ActiveMQTest.main(ActiveMQTest.java:31)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a broker that only listens on VM transport based clients but your client is using the default connection URI which is 'failover:tcp://127.0.0.1" which means that your client will hang on start waiting for the FailoverTransport to connect to the broker.  You either need to configure the connection factory to use "vm://localhost" or alter the transport connector configuration to something like:

```
broker.addConnector("tcp://localhost:61616");
```